# Parsing JSON using objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Im getting a JSON as below from a web service

```
data =     {
    following = 1;
};
message = "You are now following";
status = 1;
```

and I am trying to loop it using the following code (in order to get the value of the "following" key)

```
    for(NSDictionary *item in datarecieved){
        int placeName = [item valueForKey:@"following"];
        NSLog(@"FOLLOWING VALUE %i", placeName);
    }
```

But I am getting an exception - "uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: can you show your json?

Comment: Note that you omitted the beginning and ending `{..};` characters.  These are critical to understanding what you have, as they indicate a dictionary.  (Similarly, when showing JSON, you must be sure to include the outermost characters.)

Comment: And go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and is much easier to deal with if you understand it, vs trying to "cookbook" everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
int placeName = [datarecieved[@"data"][@"following"] intValue];
```

Comment: But for beginners it's better to do it a step at a time -- `NSDictionary* dataDict = dataReceived[@"data"];  NSNumber* followingNum = dataDict[@"following"];  int placeName = [followingNum intValue];`  Then one can examine the intermediate values to understand what's happening when it doesn't go quite right.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do like this

```
for(NSDictionary *item in datarecieved){
        if([item class] == [NSDictionary class])
        {
        int placeName = [item valueForKey:@"following"];
        NSLog(@"FOLLOWING VALUE %i", placeName);
        }
    }
```

because there are two other key in response and they dosen't contain following key

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:`?  Why are you testing the class like that rather than using `isKindOfClass`?

Answer (score 1):

Once you deserialize the JSON it will be `NSDictionary`, so you don't need to use a loop (unless you need to loop through all keys)

In your case if you just want value for `following` key, you can do the following

```
NSNumber *following = [datarecieved valueForKeyPath:@"data.following"];
NSLog(@"FOLLOWING VALUE %@", following);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need valid JSON. Look into the OP comments, there is a good address for understanding JSON.

Then you first must parse the JSON data. Assuming `datareceived` is of class `NSData`:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datareceived options:nil error:&error];

if(error) {
    NSLog(@"parsing error: %@", error);
}
else {
    for(NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The exception you are doubtless getting is *unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12345678* and is because `item` does not support that selector.

You need to check that `item` is actually an `NSDictionary` before calling `valueForKey:` (you should be using `objectForKey:` anyway):

```
for(NSDictionary *item in datarecieved){
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        int placeName = [item objectForKey:@"following"];
        NSLog(@"FOLLOWING VALUE %i", placeName);
    }
}
```

(you probably want to `break` at some point once you've found what you're looking for as well).

Comment: Thanks, but the code does not execute the "if" block, and it turns out that i am not getting the "following" value.

Comment: Looks like you need to find the `data` dictionary.  @bhargavg actually gives an answer that will probably work better for you.